# Re-visiting answered topic: Why do I get an ALSA error on a windows 11 OS? pygame issue

Tags: alsa, python-3.10, pygame-mixer

i am using pygame and pygbag o a windows 11 pro only OS, but i get this error:

```
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.10.12)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

---

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-11dff67e3bbf> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 
     11 # Load and play the downloaded music
---> 12 pg.mixer.init()  # Initialize the mixer module
     13 pg.mixer.music.load(music_file_url)
     14 pg.mixer.music.play(-1)

error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory
```

what has an ALSA error has to do with windows?

i tried using alternatives, such as sounddevice, specify the Audio Driver, checked windows settings... but i did not manage to find an explanation for this...

Comment: nb pygbag only supports pygame-ce  :  py -mpip uninstall pygame; py -m pip install pygame-ce   . Also use python official local distribution for windows, here i see ipython.